# Reconstruction of batch-acquired signal

Tags: wavelet, stft, reconstruction

I am currently working on a project which requires evaluating slow changes over time in the magnitude of a signal's high frequency (over 10 kHz) components.

This signal was acquired in tests with a 25.6 kHz sampling rate and in "batches": every minute, one second of data was acquired. This was done in order to save storage space, since 1 Hz resolution was enough for the FFT analysis and since short spaced fluctuations in the components would be irrelevant for our goal. The tests were quite expensive, and I am not able to perform more of them.

This acquisition method was enough for a STFT analysis of the signal, but we are now looking to other time-frequency analysis methods, such as Hilbert-Hwang and continuous wavelet transform, and these require data acquired at a fixed sample rate.

I see 2 options to perform these analyses with the data that I currently have:

1. Reconstruct the missing 59s of each minute assuming that the 1s of data that I have is representative of whole minute.
2. Simply join all data that I have, perform all the analyses as if the data was acquired at a 60 times slower rate, and in the end just scale the frequencies back to the original.

I tried to do both solutions with the [istft matlab function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/istft.html), tweaking with the function parameters and trying to interpolate phase and magnitude information in order to smoothen the transition from one batch to another, but I always end up with discontinuities that make it unable to perform the desired analyses.

Is there any way to reconstruct/synthesize data that would have a similar frequency behavior of the original, but correct for the discontinuities?

Comment: Interesting approach. I'm trying to see how this wouldn't be different from sampling at a 1 sample/minute rate with a 1 sec aperture. With that thought model there are significant implications of clock jitter and aliasing that would limit the fidelity of your result. Have you considered these effects? Are the high frequency components isolated to such a narrow bandwidth that a 1 sample/minute rate would allow? Otherwise for something within your 1 Hz RBW and 25.6 KHz sampling rate I see how you could use the separate captures as an ability to average out the resulting power spectrum.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I am not quite sure what you mean by aperture. Could you explain it a little more?
To give a little more context, the data I have come from accelerometers mounted on reciprocating machinery. So, for every minute of testing, I have a time series with 25600 points representing the vibration at the first second of that given minute.

Comment: I may have some time later tonight or tomorrow to detail a response if someone else doesn’t sooner. Would it be possible for you to show what a typical result would look like if you weren’t constrained by storage space? I am curious about the expected frequency fluctuation vs time and overall occupied bandwidth and how that might vary over time.